# Name for a namespace that contains countries and states?

Tags: namespaces, naming-conventions

What should I call a namespace that contains the Country and CountrySubdivision (generic term for State or Province) classes?

Comment: Not sure if this is an appropriate question for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it something like GeographicalArea